# Return value of db.collection.distinct()

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection which I have inserted into MongoDB. I would like to retrieve one particular value using db.coll.distinct(key) and use it as a value for update function. The sample Python code is as follows:

```
post = {key:value}
db.filesystem3.insert(post)
value1 = "testing"
ret = db.filesystem3.distinct(key)
db.filesystem3.update({key:ret},{"$set":{key:value1}})
result = db.filesystem3.find()
for i in result:
    print i
```

The document is not getting updated. Am I missing something here or we can not use the distinct field for update?

Comment: [`collection.distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) return a list of distinct values. Why do you think you need `.distinct`? Perhaps there is a better way to do what you wan so please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33138369/edit) to your question to show sample document with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The call to distinct returns a list, so you need to iterate over each value returned.

```
ret = db.filesystem3.distinct(key)
for ret_value in ret:
    db.filesystem3.update({key:ret_value}, {"$set": {key: value1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

ret = db.filesystem3.distinct(key) line will return an array, so you can not directly pass an array to update the document

> **Behavior of Distinct Operator**
>
> Distinct Operator Finds the distinct values for a specified field across a single collection and **returns the results in an array**.
>
> Array Fields If the value of the specified field is an array,
>   db.collection.distinct() considers each element of the array as a
>   separate value.
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

You can update your code like this

```
for(var i=0;i<ret.length;i++){
var val = ret[i];
db.filesystem3.update({key:val},{"$set":{key:value1}});
}
```

Hope it will help